# How to run a different module from main module in console applications in visual basic?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, function, module, command

I would like to run the functions of Module2 in Module1. Is there any way to achieve this by creating another command with the if function that says that "if line = "command" then" and then running the module that way? For example, if Module1 had a Console.Writeline function, and I wanted to run a Console.Writeline function that was different, but in module2, could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a new public sub with your functions, and when you make the command, just write console.clear, then on the line below that, write your new sub name. In the new sub, you can do the same thing to link back to the main sub with a command.